# How big was the planet killer from "The Doomsday Machine" episode?

Tags: star-trek, robots

I tried to look it up, but all I can find is Commodore Deckers description of the [planet killer](http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=star%20trek%20doomsday%20machine&view=detail&id=C35B802634073BCD4EFA212C5918C9CDCE19F08D&first=71):

> "Miles long, with a maw that could swallow a dozen starships,"

That's pretty big, but how big was it? Are its actual dimensions morely clearly defined or described in the Star Trek Universe?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Doomsday Machine was approximately 2700 meters long. Check out the graphics below:

[image: Scale of starships]

Image from the [Star Trek Minutia](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/engineering102A/index.html) Site - [Large Alien Spaceships](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/engineering102A/aliens_large.png)

Comment: Dude! Awesome image. I look forward to your answers.

Comment: Just a quick note, the Planet Killer's size is [a visual estimation](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/schematics/size-annotations.htm) based on comparison with the Constitution.  It's likely to be off, especially if they used the non-remastered version to come up with the number (since scale wasn't completely consistent anyway).  (I don't know if the Remastered version was better, though)

Comment: Agreed. Since this work was done before the remastered version, I am not sure if the scale remained the same.

Comment: If you liked that graphic, try this one . .  .http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/191accgnmnevzjpg/original.jpg

Comment: Hmmm... Try as I might, I can't seem to find a 1968 Chrysler Imperial with California plates on either graphic.

Answer (score 5):

2700 meters and the size comparison image both seem way too small for a mechanized behemoth possessing power vast enough to destroy an entire planet. This is admittedly a very subjective and possibly arbitrary  perception but it seems to me that a weapon of that magnitude and capability would have to be an absolute minimum of ten miles long AT LEAST. Commodore Decker described the thing as "miles long....with a maw that could swallow a dozen starships." lf we take the size of the Constitution class as approximately 300 meters long, the maw alone would have to be at least 4000 meters in diameter to accommodate that claim. Extrapolating the length by a standard factor of 8 then renders the doomsday machine about 32,000 meters long, or roughly 96,000 feet, which is equivalent to about 20 miles. This seems much more appropriate a size for such an engine of destruction.

Comment: "a dozen" is a common go-to shorthand for "several", and Decker was crazed with fear so I wouldn't consider anything he said to be reliable.

Comment: The large Xindi weapon packed similar destructive power into a sphere with a diameter less than the depth of a terrestrial world's ocean.  The planet killer's size may have had more to do with the engineering challenges (structural integrity and propulsion) of its massive neutronium armor than with its offensive capability.

Answer (score -1):

There are several scenes where the machine is first attacked by Enterprise where the Enterprise resembles an insect by comparison. As Enterprise is 300 Metres long this does give the impression that the "Machine" is many Miles/Kilometres long. Take a look and see what you think.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to include one or more relevant screenshots. That way, each individual who reads this answer wouldn't have to separately take the trouble to look it up for themselves.